# How to fail Jenkins stage on groovy condition

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want the stage to fail if this groovy condition is false: `version ==~ versionPattern`

I have tried:

```
        stage("Sanity check") {
            steps {
                script {
                    assert version !=~ versionPattern : "Build failed because git branch does not contain valid semantic version"
                }
            }
```

and:

```
        stage("Sanity check") {
            steps {
                script {
                    if(version != versionPattern) {
                        exit 1
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I do this? Both examples Jenkins just ignores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `error`:

```
if(version != versionPattern) {
  error(message: "Build failed because git branch does not contain valid semantic version.")
}
```

Comment: thanks thats it, but I had to use matcher